# Use ProxyPass configuration for Apache in docker

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, mod-proxy

How do I use ProxyPass in Apache config that links to a different container?
hard coding ip address works, but is there a more generic way to do this?

**Container1**: apache listens on port 443 proxy passes it to Container2 port 3000

**Container2**: Runs any Flask/Dancer app that listens on port 3000

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    ...
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    container_name: Container1
    network_mode: "bridge"
    depends_on: 
      - web
  web:
    ...
    container_name: Container2
    network_mode: "bridge"
```

-

```
#apache config
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  ProxyPreserveHost on
    # Works but with ip 
    #ProxyPass / http://ip-of-container2:3000/
    #ProxyPassReverse / http://ip-of-container2:3000/
  ProxyPass / http://Container2:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://Container2:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does `ping Container2` ok in Container1? What about remove `network_mode: "bridge"`？

Comment: @atline No, ping Dontainer2 from Container1 does not work but ping ip-of-Container2 works.
I was just trying to reuse the default bridge. will it anything if i remove it? Also there is "bridge" for both containers, typo while posting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `network_mode` is the issue.

I remove `network_mode` and have a test for next:

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: Container1
    #network_mode: "bridge"
    tty: true
  web:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: Container2
    #network_mode: "bridge"
    tty: true
```

After `docker-compose up -d`, I enter into `Container1` and install `ping`, I can ping `Container2`.

```
root@fe69bd6d62af:/# ping Container2
PING Container2 (172.26.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from Container2.bb_default (172.26.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.166 ms
64 bytes from Container2.bb_default (172.26.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
```

You may also reference to [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) to know what user-defined bridges bring to us compare to default bridge, the main difference is next:

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.

If you do not specify `network_mode`, compose will automatically setup a user-defined bridges for you, so you can use this magic. In my example, `bb_default` is the bridge compose setup for us, you can use `docker network ls` to confirm it. Also, could use `docker network inspect bb_default` to see details of this new bridge.